# Fund cannot be sent to accounts located in Us because its outside of your platform region

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

```
await stripe.transfers.create({
   amount: amount,
   currency: account.default_currency,
   source_transaction: chargeId,
   destination: accountId
});
```

[from stripe account (uk) to Us stripe connected account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no0sV.jpg)

Comment: Tried contacting support?

Comment: they are suggesting https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee but , in this approach , money cannot be hold ,our requirement :- client submit money to stripe company account (UK) , when professional complete jobs , client transfer money from company stripe account to prof stripe connected amount

Comment: Can you post what you did to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Stripe doesn't allow transfer to the outside of the platform region**

You can use the following method to manage a business in multiple countries

First use stripe create charge API with destination charges

```
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
  customer: data.customer,
  source: data.cardId,
  amount: amount,
  currency: user.currency,
  description: process.env.APP_NAME,
  statement_descriptor: process.env.APP_NAME,
  application_fee: platformFee,
  destination: accountId
});
```

After creating the charge, You can transfer that payout to that connected account using create payout API

```
await stripe.payouts.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
 }, {
    stripeAccount: accountId,
});
```

This flow is working for me

Comment: So a payout as opposed to a transfer and you'll be fine?

Comment: What if you need to payout to multiple accounts?