# Stripe Payment gateway

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, escrow

I'm creating service like Airbnb using Laravel. So I'm using stripe payment gateway for my project. So I want to create escrow system using stripe. Let's say someone book properties of seller ABC for 3 days. On booking amount is debit from buyer's account and credit to the admin Account. Now on journey completion seller ABC get his money and Admin get his commission from booking. So we have to transfer money to seller account only when journey is complete.

So I'm using following method to achieve this following methods.

> Payment Authorization

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_****');

\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 1099,
  'currency' => 'inr',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'capture_method' => 'manual',
]);
```

> Payment Capture

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_*****');

$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve('pi_****');
$intent->capture(['amount_to_capture' => 750]);
```

> Transfer Payment

```
// Create a Transfer to a connected account (later):
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
  'amount' => 7000,
  'currency' => 'inr',
  'destination' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  'transfer_group' => '{ORDER10}',
]);
```

But it's not working properly because I'm getting following error.

**Funds can't be sent to accounts located in IN because it's restricted outside of your platform's region;**

Can someone please guide me to achieve my requirements.

Comment: nevel share your keys on  any platform directly

Comment: It's test key so not to worry.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850563/fund-cannot-be-sent-to-accounts-located-in-us-because-its-outside-of-your-platfo

Comment: https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-india-support-for-marketplaces There are fund flows you can't do when working with a platform or connected account that may be in India, due to regulatory issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Stripe only accepts INR payouts within India.

Is your stripe account within India?

```
Stripe currently does not support the ability to receive INR payouts from Stripe accounts registered outside of India.
```

[Stripe support documentation](https://support.stripe.com/questions/currency-support-for-indian-rupees-inr-for-payouts)